# my Django website full style broken after move from localhost to shared hosting

Tags: python, django

My site can't locating where it's static and media file after upload on shared hosting. Here is my

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/project32/rootfolder/media/' #this is the path of my hosing media root file

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/project32/rootfolder/static/'   #this is the path of my hosing static root file
```

**root urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

where I am doing mistake? why my website can't locating the static folder on my shared hosing ?
I also run `python manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem solved after adding adding STATIC_URL path in my root urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    
    ]
    
urlpatterns +=  static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns +=  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

You should delete the 'STATIC_ROOT' line. You should use it this way.